# content-driven ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I have one **ShowActivity** with two **Textview** and one **imageView**.Texviews getting resources from string.xml and showing that on ShowActivity,I WANNA MAKE IMAGEVIEW LIKE THAT.

How it possible to imageview getting resources from drawble for each subjects_numbers?

This is my textview code :

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
String stringName_2 = "subject_text_" + String.valueOf(Subject_number);
int resID_2 = getResources().getIdentifier(stringName_2, "string", getPackageName());
tv2.setText(resID_2);
```

I wanna code like this for my Imageview. I MADE it but it DOESN'T WORK..

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview_x);

 String imageName = "image_"+ String.valueOf(Subject_number);

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable",getPackageName());
img.setImageResource(resID);
```

CAN ANYONE HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + imageName, null, null);
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```